# How to load schema, set properties and output a string without SDO?

Tags: php, xml, sdo

After struggling with installing SDO on the server I found some information that SDO is not going to be further developed/supported.

How could this be done without SDO?

```
$das = SDO_DAS_XML::create("$someSchemaFile");
$doc = $das->createDocument();
$root = $doc->getRootDataObject();
$root->Data1 = 'data1';
$root->Data2 = 'data2';
$string = $das->saveString($doc);
```

Schema (pseudo)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cc="http://cc/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="SomeName">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Data1" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="Data2" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: So your goal is lot load a schema file (xsd), set some properties in the XML, and output the XML string? Can you post the contents of the xsd?

Comment: Yes that is exactly my goal. Unfortunately I can't post the schema file.

Comment: Can you invent a schema file that is abbreviated and similar in spirit & structure to the one you can't post?

Comment: I think so. Give me few minutes

Comment: Could you maybe update the question title to summarise what "this" is? Would make for a more useful and easily found question.

Comment: @deceze Sure, I have changed the title, thank you. Please feel free to edit it if you think it could be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSD is XML itself, so you have several ways to go about it, like for instance [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). But the easiest way would probably be [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php), it's not quite as powerful but mostly you don't need that anyway.

Here's a little example:

```
$xml = <<<XML <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:cc="http://cc/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="SomeName">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Data1" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="Data2" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element> </xsd:schema> 
XML;

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// get the first xsd:element node with a name-attribute of 'Data1' 
$element = $doc->xpath("//xsd:element[@name='Data1']")[0];

// change the name-attribute: 
$element->attributes()->name = 'SomeOtherName';

// or even add another attribute: 
$element->addAttribute('newAttribute', 'newAttributeValue');

// and spit it out as XML again:
echo $doc->asXML();
```

I hope this helps, since I'm not quite sure if that's what you had in mind. But as far as I understood your question you're just looking for an alternative / easy way to manipulate an XML file.